# How to setup an environment for UCMA 4.0 development

Tags: ucma

I want to get started with UCMA 4.0 development.

I want to build a single VM environment where I can install all the dependencies of UCMA SDK.

Is there a guide anywhere to build such a dev environment?

I found this
http://www.computer-talk.com/en/blog/item/building-a-standalone-lync-server-or-how-to-write-ucma-applications-on-a-plane

But it seems that in order to install this ... I would need to know how to install "exchange" and "lync server"

I tried installing Exchange and Lync 2013 server.. but faced too many problems.. because I am not so familiar with Lync Infrastructure (and it has its roots to many other types of infrastructure like AD, Exchange etc).

I will be grateful, if you could point me to a step by step guide which shows how to setup a single vm infra for UCMA development.

or perhaps there is a pre-build VM somewhere which I can download and use without the need to setup my own.

Comment: hi how is it going? if you want to set up with VMs, you must create at lease two vms, one for AD/DNS server while the other for lync server. you can do like this: http://windowspbx.blogspot.hk/2012/07/step-by-step-installing-lync-server.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Lync Server 2013 VM available on the Microsoft Download site that includes UCMA 4.0. However, it is intended as a demo so I expect it will time-out on you after a certain number of weeks.

[Test Drive - Lync Server 2013 - Part 1 of 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40266)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but figured out that you cannot setup Lync environment on single VM to test your UCMA Application.

Here is what I have setup on my Laptop for UCMA Application testing using Virtualbox.

Server 1: AD server. 
 
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 
RAM: 512 (I know its low but works perfectly for me, also you wont be using this server frequently)
HDD: 25GB
Roles : ADDS, DNS, DHCP(optional, but its easy when used), IIS, Certificate Authority.

Server 2: Lync/Skype (I used Skype for Business evaluation version)
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 (If possible run windows update before installing Skype) 
RAM : 2GB+ (More the merrier)
HDD : 30GB+ 
Roles : Skype/Lync Server, IIS, and some other features which I don't remember on top of my head, I ll update it later)

Server 3: UCMA Application Server 
 
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 
RAM: 512MB 
HDD: 25GB
Required : .net framework 4.0+, UCMA 4.0 SDK.

Now that we have what is required on Server End, we need clients. Download Lync Client, (Lync client works with Skype for business server as well) and install them on host system and Server1,

Now we have 3 server and 2 clients(Lync client installed on Server 1 and Host machine)

This is just an overview how you can proceed and plan your resources, there are lot more steps involved when you publish topology and add your application in Trusted Application Pool.